# What is the English translation of the letter (written in Japanese) in Anohana: The Movie?

Tags: anohana

So I began watching *Anohana: The Movie* after completing the series. In the movie, there's this scene where Anaru is writing a letter to Menma. Unfortunately, the contents of the letter are left untranslated. Can someone please tell me what Anaru wrote in the letter?

Here is the screenshot of the letter:

[image]

Comment: The very last part says "I like Jintan". I don't know enough Japanese to get the rest.

Comment: roughly last two line, *from when... from when, i....  like jintan*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transcript:

> めんまに[謝]{あやま}りたいから、お[願]{ねが}い[叶]{かな}えようって[思]{おも}ってた 
>   I want to apologize to Menma, so I think my wish has been granted.
>
> いつからか... いつからか、[私]{わたし}...　じんたいが[好]{す}き 
>   Since when... Since (who knows) when... I fell in love with Jintai.

いつからか means [“since some time or another; since who-knows-when”](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%95%E6%99%82%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B), but I am not very sure how to put it to make it sound natural in English.